# Using $timeout to execute function in a service only after a certain amount of time has passed?

Tags: angularjs

http://jsbin.com/vozohexomo/4/edit?js,console,output

I have a service which makes $http calls and two directives. One directive is responsible for passing data to the service (`my-input`), the other directive is responsible for processing the results of the service (`my-output`).

The goal here is to enable the user to perform live-searching and have the results displayed in real-time.

Right now all it does is add a delay to the execution of the query, which is pointless. How would I go about making this execute the query only after a resting period?

```
app.service('httpFactory', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {  
  this.doQuery = function (query) {
    $timeout(function(){
      console.log("Executing: " + query);
      $rootScope.data = "the result of query " + query;
    }, 500);
  };
});

app.directive('myInput', ['httpFactory', function(httpFactory) {
  var link = function(scope, elem) {
    scope.query = '';
    scope.$watch('query', function() {
      httpFactory.doQuery(scope.query);
    });
  };

  return {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {query: '='},
    template: '<input ng-model="query">'
  };
}]);

app.directive('myOutput', function($rootScope) {  
  var link = function(scope, elem) {
    $rootScope.$watch('data', function(){
      console.log("I see " + $rootScope.data);
    });
  };

  return {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>I see {{data}}</div>'
  };
});
```

Comment: What difference do you make between "add a delay to the execution of the query" and "execute the query only after a resting period"? You consider the former pointless, and the latter desirable, but I don't see any difference. BTW, isn't what you want exactly the inverse of "in real-time"?

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry for the confusion. The difference was I only wanted a query to execute after a brief period of user inactivity, rather than for every single key press (to avoid spamming the server with pointless requests and lagging the app with undesired results) vaguely similar to the way google will auto-render a search page as you type. I figured something out.

Comment: Look for "debounce" in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions. That could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/vozohexomo/5/edit?js,console,output

Turns out the solution was simpler than I gave it credit for. Simply hold each query in a tempQuery and only execute the one that matches after the $timeout delay.

```
app.service('httpFactory', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
  var tempQuery;
  this.doQuery = function (query) {
    tempQuery = query;
    $timeout(function(){
      if (query == tempQuery) {
        console.log("Executing: " + query);
        $rootScope.data = "the result of query " + query;
      }
    }, 500);
  };
});
```

Comment: @JB Nizet was right, debounce is usually what you want for things like this. However, if you insist on having your service contain the logic, instead of the if (query == tempQuery) I'd suggest simply doing a $timeout.cancel(query) before the $timeout block. That, to me, reads obviously like you only want a single timeout to execute.

Comment: @Rytmis Yes, I'm going with debounce as it's exactly what I need. Trade-off is having to duplicate the debounce in my boilerplate, but worth it for keeping the service clean and free from a forced delay.